# How do I change the value of a SharedPreference without going into the preference screen?

Tags: android

I have a string I want to store in my SharedPreferences. Is there some kind of setString I could do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username", "myUsername");
editor.commit();
```

You can make changes in the SharedPreferences, and commit the changes after you are done.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Let me try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceFileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("StringNameToBeStored", "value");
    editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can do everything in the same line, there's no need to declare editor

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("username", "myUsername").commit();
```

And don't forget the commit!